# How to combine two tables and use one name to call. [codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How do I combine two table into one. For example I have two tables:

**Form:**
Title
applicant
remark

**Letter:**
Title
sender
remark

How can i combine two of them since the applicant and sender has different column name.
After combining, i can call using one name so for example:
document.title, document.sender, document.remark
where document.sender has form.applicant and letter.sender combined.

Comment: can you please explain it more? Do you want it to call in view or in controller?

Comment: show your complete table structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about an SQL query, you could use a UNION SELECT, but since I'm not using MySql, I don't know, if it's working there.

`SELECT Titel, Applicant, Remark FROM Form UNION SELECT Title, Sender, Remark FROM Letter`

Of course the data type of the combined columns should match.

Comment: Thanks I got it. **Addition:** use AS 'name' if combining two different column names.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside of array

**Code:**

```
$document = array(
    'title' => "Document Title",
    'remark' => "Document Remark",
    'sender' => array(
        "form" => array(
            'applicant' => ' Sender Applicant',
            'letter_sender' => ' Letter Sender'
        )
    )
);

echo $document['title'] . "<br />";
echo $document['remark'] . "<br />";
echo $document['sender']['form']['applicant'] . "<br />";
echo $document['sender']['form']['letter_sender'] . "<br />"
```

**Result:**

```
Document Title
Document Remark
senderApplicant
Letter Sender
```